# How to count the last/latest close date where "Open_Close" col_status = "Colse" based on partition by ID?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to count/flip flop count for the last/latest close date where "Open_Close" col_status = "Close" based on partition by ID.

Sample Dataset:-

```
ID  Status      Date        Amount  Open_Close
-----------------------------------------------
1   New         01/05/20    20      Open
1   Removed     02/05/20    30      Close
1   New         02/05/20    50      Open
1   In-Progress 03/05/20    20      Open
1   Fixed       04/05/20    50      Close
2   New         05/05/20    30      Open
2   Removed     05/05/20    20      Close
3   New         05/05/20    30      Open
3   Assigned    05/05/20    50      Open
3   In-Progress 05/05/20    20      Open
3   Fixed       09/05/20    50      Close
4   New         12/05/20    20      Open
4   Assigned    13/05/20    30      Open
4   Fixed       13/05/20    20      Close
```

Expected Results:-

```
ID  Status      Date        Amount  Open_Close  Flipflop_count
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   New         01/05/20    20      Open            3
1   Removed     02/05/20    30      Close           3
1   New         02/05/20    50      Open            3
1   In-Progress 03/05/20    20      Open            3
1   Fixed       04/05/20    50      Close           3
2   New         05/05/20    30      Open            1
2   Removed     05/05/20    20      Close           1
3   New         05/05/20    30      Open            1
3   Assigned    05/05/20    50      Open            1
3   In-Progress 05/05/20    20      Open            1
3   Fixed       09/05/20    50      Close           1
4   New         12/05/20    20      Open            1
4   Assigned    13/05/20    30      Open            1
4   Fixed       13/05/20    20      Close           1
```

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: can you translate in to sql query ?

Comment: very similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687176/how-to-count-record-changes-for-a-particular-value-of-a-column-in-a-scala-datafr